# How to Open a Worksheet at TODAY()+2?

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple Excel worksheets with dates in col B. I use the following VBA code block to open the worksheet with today's date visible on screen.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim d As Date, i As Long

d = Date

ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1

    For i = 16 To Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(i, "B").Value = d Then
            Cells(i, "B").Select
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

The date column does not contain dates for the weekend so the coding only works when today is between Monday and Friday. If I open the sheet on a Saturday it opens at the top of the sheet, which can be thousands of rows away from today's date as the sheet contains historical data dating back several years.

How do I amend the coding so that if today's date is not in col B it increments today's date by 2 and searches for the VBA equivalent of TODAY()+2, so that it will open the sheet with Monday's date visible if today is Saturday, or Tuesday's date visible if today is Sunday?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but if it's a weekend, it'll increment the date by two; otherwise it will remain as today's date.

Replace:

`d = Date`

with

`d=Evaluate("=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(TODAY())=7,WEEKDAY(TODAY())=1),TODAY()+2,TODAY())")`

But also you may want to reconsider looping through every cell to find what you're looking for. If you have a large dataset it might take a while consider replacing it with this:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ActiveSheet.Range("B:B"), d) > 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("B:B").Find(d).Activate
End If
```

the `countif` just ensures that the cell value actually exists and doesn't error when you try to activate it.

Answer (score 0):

Disregard!  After more experimenting I've managed to resolve it, it simply needed 1 more line of code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim d As Date, i As Long

d = Date

ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1

    For i = 16 To Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(i, "B").Value = d Then
            Cells(i, "B").Select
            Exit Sub
        Else:  d = Date + 2

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I feel like this might not work all the time. Imagine a scenario where its Saturday, and `B16` contains Monday's date. If you run this, it'll increment `d` by two, but if `B17` doesn't also contain Monday's date it won't match and it'll increment to Wednesday's date and it'll continue on like that. A similar thing would happen during the weekdays if `B16` didn't contain the current day's date.